# Python Scipy Anneal finding solutions out of range

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using Scipy in Python to do a simulated anneal. I give the anneal an upper and lower limit with the following commands:

```
optimize.anneal(f, input_vector0, lower = 0, upper = 2*np.pi)
```

The anneal algorithm totally ignores the lower and upper parameters and searches way outside of that space... Does anyone know why? Here's the 'solution' it finds:

> 31.6237632627
>   -42.2752494373
>   39.5493204901
>   -40.0042611884
>   43.6152270079
>   156.037896659
>   -94.2145500736
>   34.2889218355
>   1.38692105848
>   -55.5107545279
>   -173.884187212
>   95.7485871187
>   -126.122806244
>   -80.6862568532
>   -8.24522935611
>   31.0745563981
>   -26.1692693183
>   -15.4530723302
>   10.8388939531
>   -0.331091602947
>   -103.301042697
>   -47.7445000946
>   20.9176159149
>   46.2024960212
>   -73.3695426792
>   -120.496928699
>   -37.7412899302
>   -98.0482535989
>   78.034510108
>   51.6923809382
>   -142.940610675
>   84.9461667872
>   8.08078933482
>   -36.2926389711

Comment: try to increase `maxiter` and check your initial guess given by `input_vector0`, if it is not out of your limits...

Comment: @SaulloCastro the input vector is the zero vector (in bounds). I'll try the maxiter parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I looked at scipy's anneal a few years ago, my reading of the code was that `lower` and `upper` are limits on the random draws which limit the step size.

They are not limits on the parameters itself. This means anneal is not a constraint solver.

See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1653

Nobody has volunteered so far to clean up and enhance anneal (open source).