# lower and upper in scipy.optimize.anneal not working

Tags: python, scipy

I seem to be calling this scipy function incorrectly, since the result it's returning does not respect the lower and upper boundaries I've specified.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

def fn2(args):
    x,y,z = args
    return x + y - z

opt.anneal(fn2, [0, 0, 0], lower=[5, 5, -5], upper = [15, 15, 5])
(array([-2240.14994625, -1878.50139022,  2297.86619576]), 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look hard enough:

[Python Scipy Anneal finding solutions out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795235/python-scipy-anneal-finding-solutions-out-of-range)

It seems that this is really a documentation error in scipy - lower and upper are NOT used to constrain the domain, despite [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.12.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html#scipy.optimize.anneal):

**lower, upper** : float or ndarray
Lower and upper bounds on x.